# Problem involving roots of unity

Tags: roots-of-unity

Let $\varepsilon _k$ be $\cos \frac {2k \pi} {n} + i \sin \frac {2k \pi} {n}$. Find the value of the product:
$$\prod _ {k=1}^n (2+\varepsilon _k-\varepsilon _k^2).$$

Comment: did you try anything?

Comment: I don't know how to start. I calculated the product for $n=2,3,4$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $z^n-1=0$ :
$$
\prod_1^n(2+\varepsilon_k-\varepsilon_k^2)=\prod_1^n-(-1-\varepsilon_k)(2-\varepsilon_k)=(-1)^n
\prod_1^n(-1-\varepsilon_k)\prod_1^n(2-\varepsilon_k)=(-1)^n((-1)^n-1)(2^n-1)
$$

Comment: Nice! Good job!

Comment: Looks correct to me. It may be simpler to say that it is zero when $n$ is even and $2(2^n-1)$ when $n$ is odd.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks.